# Visualforce displays decimal number 0.43 as .43

Tags: visualforce, pdf, formatting, decimal

I am trying to display numbers with up to 2 decimal places in my Visualforce PDF. If the number is bigger than 1 (i.e. there is no 0 at its front), the value is shown correctly. However, in cases where the number is greater than 0 and smaller than 1, the 0 at the front is dropped and the number is just shown as .43. I want it to display the number as 0.43 instead.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to render these numbers:

```
<td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
                    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,###.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
                        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputtext>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
                    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,###.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
                        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c * expansionVatRatio}"/>
                    </apex:outputtext>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
                    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,###.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
                        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c * (1 + expansionVatRatio)}"/>
                    </apex:outputtext>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display numbers with up to 2 decimal places in your Visualforce PDF, you have used the `apex:outputText` with the formatting `{0,number,###,###.00}`.

The issue with your formatting parameter. You need to pass `{0,number,###,##0.00}` instead of the `{0,number,###,###.00}`.

Using this formatting you can display `0.43` instead of the `.43`

Your code is updated as below:

```
<td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,##0.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c}"/>
    </apex:outputtext>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,##0.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c * expansionVatRatio}"/>
    </apex:outputtext>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; border:0.40px solid black; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:3px;">
    <apex:outputtext value="{0,number,###,##0.00}" styleClass="marginLeft2px">
        <apex:param value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c * (1 + expansionVatRatio)}"/>
    </apex:outputtext>
</td>
```

Comment: <apex:outputField value="{!billingLine.AcctSeed__Total__c * expansionVatRatio}" styleClass="marginLeft2px"/> doesn't seem to be a valid expression: <apex:outputField> can only take values of fields and nothing else. We can't do mathematical operations on field values inside <apex:outputField>.

Comment: @hajidayi, I have updated my answer. Check and let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!